# Enabling VPN split tunnelling at the OS level

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, vpn, split-tunnel

I'm creating a generic sandbox VM that can be given to a variety of potential corporate customers. I need to be able to query a specific ip address from a whitelisted source to access some of the features.

However some clients want to install VPNs on their system, this means that the destination ip of the query is now not on the whitelist.

To get around this I have enabled split tunnelling per VPN provider, I am wondering if there is an OS level way to do this so that I don't have to enable split tunnelling per VPN provider. (Yes I'm aware this is somewhat of a longshot.)

I have seen the powershell command `Set-VpnConnection “VPN Connection Name” -SplitTunneling $true` but I can't see how to get the "VPN Connection Name" reliably.