# Per-application split tunneling with self-hosted VPN or proxy

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, wireguard, split-tunnel

What's the easiest way to split tunnel individual processes, not just CIDR ranges, with self-hosted VPNs or SOCKS proxies? Mainly applies to Windows, but it would be nice if it works similarly on Linux too.

What I want is to just set up a tunnel with WireGuard, OpenVPN or any protocol and have a client app that lets me connect to my own VPN server and allows including/exluding running applications to/from the tunnel the same as any other commercial VPNs.

Are there any such clients that support split tunneling and most modern VPN protocols, and are preferrably FOSS? Some guides on how to set up a VPN server on Linux and connect to it from Android or Linux clients feature basic split tunneling, but I couldn't find anything remotely similar on Windows.

Most open source clients developed by commercial VPNs like PIA, Mullvad, ProtonVPN, Mozilla VPN, etc. already have that exact functionality but don't offer the ability to connect to arbitrary VPN servers. As far as I know, they achieve split tunneling with a driver service selectively routing the traffic through the VPN's virtual network interface.

I found these similar questions without helpful answers:

- [Self-Hosted Wireguard VPN with per-application split tunnelling?](https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/t1s1pa/selfhosted_wireguard_vpn_with_perapplication)
- [Application based split tunneling](https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenVPN/comments/cjucv0/application_based_split_tunneling)
- [Wireguard with split tunneling (Windows) possible?](https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/ktythr/wireguard_with_split_tunneling_windows_possible)
- [Self hosted Split Tunnel VPN](https://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/comments/ujjmkl/self_hosted_split_tunnel_vpn)
- [How do these VPNs achieve per-app tunneling?](https://superuser.com/questions/1375841/how-do-these-vpns-achieve-per-app-tunneling)
- [How do commercial VPNs achieve app-level split tunnel in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1709887/how-do-commercial-vpns-achieve-app-level-split-tunnel-in-windows)
- [Enabling VPN split tunnelling at the OS level](https://superuser.com/questions/1691880/enabling-vpn-split-tunnelling-at-the-os-level)

Comment: Hello! I am working on an application that solves this issue. It is currently in the early stages of development and based on the WireGuard protocol. I'm in need of testers. I put a site up https://tunnl.to if you're interested in trying it out please get in contact!